# Select the first record of another table inside a select - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I´m trying to make a query listing all clients, and also get the last comment and 
 the date of that comment inside the table of history_client inside a single query for it to be listed.

```
select a.id_client,a.name,a.lastname,(select b.date_created,b.comentary 
from history_of_client b where a.id_client = b.id_client_asociate) from clients_main_table
```

Comment: Can you update the sample data and expected output

Comment: specially I desire most than get the last date of the historial of the client, I want to get the coment of that last date too, thank you.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an inner join on max(date_created) for id_client on history table and join

```
SELECT a.id_client,a.name,a.lastname, h.commentary
FROM clients_main_table a 
INNER join (
  select b.id_client_asociate, max(b.date_created) max_date
  from history_of_client 
  group by  b.id_client_asociate ) t on t.id_client_asociate = a.id_client 
INNER JOIN history_of_client h on h.id_client_asociate = t.id_client_asociate 
      and h.date_created = t.max_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the LEFT JOIN and INNER join to get your desired result set.

```
select a.id_client,
       a.name,
       a.lastname,
       hc.date_created,
       hc.comentary
from clients_main_table c
     left join (select id_client_asociate,max(date_created) dt from history_of_client group by id_client_asociate) h
       on (c.id_client = b.id_client_asociate)
     inner join history_of_client hc
       on (hc.id_client_asociate = b.id_client_asociate and hc.date_created = h.date_created)
```

Comment: Isn't left join inner join the same as inner join inner join?

Comment: I added inner join because in question, he/she added an inline column so might chance for some record doesn't have matching records.

Comment: I don't see how that would work- but I've not had any coffee yet, so maybe I'm just missing something